# Angular component doesn't take array of strings for styles

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular 5/cli. When I have a single style url ( styleUrls:['./home.component.css'] ) everything is good, but when I add a common style sheet to the array ('../../styles.css') I get an error:

Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../styles.css', './home.component.css']
})
```

I'm pretty sure it is an array of strings. What's wrong here?

Update:
Styles added to the angular-cli.json will result in a merged style sheet file. **Don't need** to include common css in a component styleUrls.

```
...
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "./styles.css"
],
...
```

Comment: Remove the ./ from home.component.css

Comment: That won't resolve anything ...

Comment: Maybe you should create another style sheet, that isn't an asset ?

Comment: can you share the webpack file ?

Comment: Does ../../style.css actually exist?

Comment: @rrd file exists. Edited question with a solution. However I would expect it to work if I simply reference common css from within component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add styles by using @import in the component css file. For example, consider next structure:

```
src
|-app
   |-new_component
      |-new_component.component.ts
      |-new_component.component.html
      |-new_component.component.css
   | \\ etc.
|-style.css
| \\ etc.
```

in "new_component.component.css" you can use:

```
@import '../../styles.css';
```